# NSUserDefaults does not pick up setting

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I am quite new to coding in Objective C and using the settings bundle but here is what I coded.

```
    // Set the application defaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YES"
                                                        forKey:@"gameSave"];
    [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
    [defaults synchronize];   
    // Get user preference
    gameSave = [defaults boolForKey:@"saveGame"];
    NSLog(@"Save Game = %@", gameSave ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

This is my settings bundle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"       "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
        <key>FooterText</key>
        <string>www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <true/>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>gameSave</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Save Game</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>StringsTable</key>
<string>Root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When tested the gameSave value is NO or false. Can someone point me to a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@"YES"` is a `NSString`, not a `NSNumber` containing a boolean.

You want `@YES` instead:

```
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@YES
                                                    forKey:@"gameSave"];
```

Or the same, shorter:

```
NSDictionary *appDefaults = @{@"gameSave": @YES};
```

Edit: what if you do... this?

```
// Set the application defaults -- only if not written yet
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"gameSave"] == nil)
{
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"gameSave"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

// Get user preference
gameSave = [defaults boolForKey:@"gameSave"];
NSLog(@"Save Game = %@", gameSave ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work for me. I appreciate the answer. I have the setting also set to YES and it is defined as a boolean. But something must be amiss. Thanks.

Comment: Your user defaults were already registered. You need to erase the application from your device/simulator (not just kill it) and restart it so it can re-register your new defaults.

Comment: I did a rest on the simulator and closed it down and did a rebuild with the same results...it still prints NO to the console. Thanks for your quick reply. I used this same feature in another app and it worked. So I am puzzled? Thanks for your help.

Comment: if (defaults[@"gameSave"] == nil) gives me Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSUserDefaults *'

Comment: Sorry, I meant `[defaults objectForKey:@"gameSave"]` -- subscripting is not available to user defaults.

Comment: So sorry to report another issue : No visible @interface for 'NSUserDefaults' declares the selector 'objectforkey:' You have been so helpful please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: `objectforkey` has to be written `objectForKey`, capitalization matters.

Comment: Careless of me. It still seems to return NO. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: It works..... the key names were out of whack.....so thankful for this forum and especially for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm here precisely for this reason ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should be straight forward:

To save the bool:

```
// Write the value to NSUserDefault
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"gameIsSaved"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

To retrieve the boolean value

```
//Read the value from NSUserDefault
bool gameIsSaved = [defaults boolForKey:@"gameIsSaved"];
NSLog(@"gameIsSaved = %@", gameIsSaved ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: Thank you for replying I'm sure your suggestion would have worked as well.